# Table design with one pixel width & height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to design a table with height and width of 1px.
Is this possible, cause I couldn't do that?
Any advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I did it, actually I needed to use `!important` in my css style, but the space between cells are present. How should I remove them?

```
<table width="100%" style="height:1px !important;">    
<tr style="height:1px !important;">    
<td style="background-color:red; width:1px;">    
</td>    
<td style="background-color:blue; width:1px;">    
</td>    
<td style="background-color:orange;">    
</td>    
<td style="background-color:red; width:1px;">    
</td>    
</tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: What on earth for?

Comment: yes you can, what did you tried?

Comment: I'm capturing a movie from my desktop and turning it to bits to send via Internet, I made one, it was about 40KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an HTML-only answer that works across browsers and settings:

```
<body>
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr><td width=1 height=1></td></tr>
</table>
```

To set the color of the pixel, you can use the `bgcolor` attribute on the `td` element.

I can’t imagine what your purpose is, but this answers the question that was asked.

Comment: well, I'm capturing a movie from my desktop and turning it to bits to send via Internet, I made one, it was about 40KB. thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just take a look at this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yaAJ7/

It is better practice to use DIV's though rather than tables

Comment: Don't forget border-collapse.

Comment: Actually problem solved with !important for widths and heights. tnx everyone